# How to apply updates downloaded by yum-cron?

Tags: centos7, yum

I have yum-cron running on a new Centos 7 server.  I noticed in the daily emails that it sent me that the same packages were appearing every day.  On further inspection, I found that this is because I had the following setting in my `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf` file.

```
download_updates = yes
apply_updates = no
```

So yum-cron is downloading the updates, but never actually installing them.

I haven't touched the config, so these are the default settings.

My main question is, how exactly should I install the updates that yum-cron has downloaded for me?

I've been searching for an answer to this, but all I've been able to find is a dozen posts/tutorials on setting up yum-cron, and all of them just instruct you to set `apply_updates = yes` with no further explanation.  There must be a reason why `apply_updates = no` is the default setting.  I'm guessing it's to prevent some problem with an update leaving your system in a broken state while you're asleep.  To me, this seems pretty sensible, provided you know how to install the updates when you're ready.

**Edit to clarify the question:**
To be clear, I'm not asking how to make yum-cron automatically install the updates... I know that already, a dozen tutorials have told me to set `apply_updates = yes`.  My question is, suppose I leave the default behaviour with `apply_updates = no` then yum-cron will download but not install the updates, so in that case how do I *manually* install the updates that yum-cron downloaded for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is that simple and that practical !
I have set it up my self on a bunch of one-app servers and it works like a charm (you need to restart the service of course).

That being said, there could be some criticals machine that need to be handled with care before any update (make a vm snapshot, test the app after the update) with those i'd recommand a manual update just in case

to do so, maybe try

#yum update  -C

which makes yum use cache to install packages,

Comment: Thanks for the reply but you have not answered my question at all.  I'm not asking how to make yum-cron automatically install the updates.  I'm asking how can I *manually* install the updates that yum-cron has downloaded for me?

Comment: my bad, please check the edit

Comment: Yes thanks `yum update -C` is what I was looking for to install the updates that were already downloaded by yum-cron.